# How to enable web anlytics in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, web-analytics, sharepoint-2013

When opening the "Site Web Analytics reports" page in my SharePoint 2013 website I'm getting the following message: 
*"A web analytics report is not available for this site. Usage processing may be disabled on this server or the usage data for this site has not been processed yet."*

I did configure the usage and health data collection for my SharePoint Server and activated the reporting feature for my SharePoint website.
Still i'm not getting any web analytics data from my SharePoint website.

Is there somebody able to help me with this problem?

**Edit:** It seems like the database (WSS_UsageApplication) is filled with data.
I don't understand why SharePoint keeps telling me that there isn't any data available.

Comment: I've got the same problem.  My WSS_Logging database is also huge.  Not sure if the two are related.